# Node graph for multi-host ROS network

Tags: ros, rqt-graph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming a situation where nodes are distributed on multiple hosts, is there a way to oversee at a single view which nodes are running on which hosts?

I imagine something like `rqt_graph`, with which has an option to show either `ROS_IP` or `ROS_HOSTNAME` values on each node. I found [this page in rocon tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rocon_gateway_graph/Tutorials/indigo/Gateway%20Graph) but doesn't seem to provide what I'm looking for.

It can be a useful debug tool multiple hosts ROS network.

Here whether it's a single or multi ROS master network does not matter to me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228227/node-graph-for-multi-host-ros-network/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2016-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure, but does the [multimaster_fkie/node_manager](http://fkie.github.io/multimaster_fkie/node_manager.html) show this info?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-03-25**:
Although I don't find exactly what I asked on `multimaster_fkie/node_manager`, I guess `multimaster_fkie` pkg might be the best practical solution in ROS1 for communication between ROS masters. (Cont'd)

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-03-25**:
multimaster_fkie requires running synchronization nodes per each ROS master (as in [the tutorial](http://goo.gl/gNHzcv)) AFAIK, but I don't know any examples that dynamically discover masters.